# React native google signin is asking for google drive permission

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I have made a app with google signin but google asks for google drive permissions. how can i remove google drive permissions in the app? i don't want to show a popup that is asking for google drive permissions.

```
firebaseGoogleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      // add any configuration settings here:
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      this.setState({ userInfo: userInfo, loggedIn: true });
      // create a new firebase credential with the token
      const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(userInfo.idToken, userInfo.accessToken)
      // login with credential
      const firebaseUserCredential = await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        // user cancelled the login flow
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        // operation (f.e. sign in) is in progress already
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        // play services not available or outdated
      } else {
        // some other error happened
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I realized you have to remove scope property from the google configure method.

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
            scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'], // what API you want to access on behalf of the user, default is email and profile
            webClientId: '--------------- your web client id ---------',
        });
```